# Uneven distances between the edges when extruding

Tags: modeling

I have the following mesh:
[image]

When I try to inset it, the distances between the edges are in equal distance:

[image]

But when I try to extrude them (by pressing *e* then *s*), I get uneven distances between the edges:

[image]

How can I extrude the edges evenly/do an inverted inset?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the Offset Edges add-on for Blender 2.80: https://blenderartists.org/t/offset-edges/584283/200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is a *Shrink/Fatten* but with a simple series of vertices. I don't think you can do it with simple vertices but you could do it with a trick: Use the faces normals.

- Extrude up your mesh.
- <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to *Extrude Region (Vertex Normals)*.
- Drag to get what you want.
- Only keep the shape you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank you sooooo much!!!